# Specify slot sharing group for a specific task manager in Flink 1.14.0

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying the fine-grained resource management feature in Flink 1.14, hoping it can enable assigning certain operators to certain TaskManagers. Following the sample code in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/, I can now define the task sharing groups I would like (using setExternalResource-method), but I do not see any option to "assign" a TaskManager worker instance with the capabilities of this "external resource".
So to the question. Following the GPU-based example in [1](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/), how can I ensure that Flink "knows" which task manager actually has the required GPU?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the excellent flink mailing list, I now have the solution.  Basically, add lines to flink-conf.yaml for the specific task manager as per the [external resource documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/advanced/external_resources/). For a resource entitled 'example', these are the two lines that must be added:

```
external-resources: example
external-resource.example.amount: 1
```

.. will match a task a task sharing group with the added external resource:

```
.setExternalResource("example", 1.0)
```